# internet explorer 9 status bar add icons

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, icons, internet-explorer-9

I want to add some icons on the internet explorer 9 status bar. The status bar is enabled, but  it only shows me the icons/information of the page zoom.
I would like to have the icon showing javascript errors, and other javascript related calls.

How can I add icons to the status bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the option you are referring-to has been removed and never put back, in spite of many angry IE developers.

Your only option is either to go back to IE8, before Microsoft had the brilliant idea of removing this icon, or to use a debug tool that includes a console for error display.

The official Microsoft tool was mentioned already by @Tom Wijsman.

I personally recommend the free [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite), as its console is still way ahead of IE9's console.
See also the article [10 Reasons Why You Should Be Using Firebug](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/10-reasons-why-you-should-be-using-firebug/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have the icon showing javascript errors, and other Javascript related calls.

These were removed because that system was annoying to users (JS error pop-ups and what not).

Developers can just press <kbd>F12</kbd> and click on console, errors are not cleared upon refresh by default such that you can freely browse around and see the errors afterwards. This is how many developers program and it works pretty well...

If you want, you can even alert or log your errors to your server and output them the way you like:

```js
window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {
   // * 1. Do an AJAX POST to your server here, jQuery makes this easy.
   // * 2. Place it in another debugging window, or a floating debug div.
   // * 3. window.alert() ;)
};
```

— http://devblog.xing.com/frontend/how-to-log-javascript-errors/